# Is there any way to do wifi provisioning using ble in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi, wifi-direct

I want to scan the BLE device list, connect to that device, set WiFi provisioning for that device, and manage that device using WiFi.

I tried many packages and plugins for creating apps for BLE support and WiFi provisioning but I didn't get any confident information about that.